# Google Apps Script function executes when I run it manually, but fails when run as trigger, citing error code INTERNAL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google Forms linked to a Google Sheets. Within the Google Sheets, I have an Google Apps Script function that separates the input from Google Forms and stores each item row by row. I have a VLookup setup to pull information from another spreadsheet, based on the parsing from the Google Apps Script. Once the information is pulled, I then email the information to the email provided through Google Forms. I have a trigger setup to automatically run the function when the form is submitted. The picture below is the form results in the sheet.

[Form submission information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZAfz.png)

The trigger works when I select some options on Google Forms. Once I select more options, around 20+, it returns the following error code:

> We're sorry, the JavaScript engine reported an unexpected error. Error code INTERNAL.

When I run the function manually though, it executes perfectly. I'm not quite sure what the issue is. The only other question with this issue that I've found is [Web App call fails with "... Error code INTERNAL" with Custom API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967246/web-app-call-fails-with-error-code-internal-with-custom-api), but I'm already using openByID. The e in the function onFormSubmit below is my attempt at using the form object, but I haven't gotten that to work. I don't believe this causes the problem though.

```
//Object to store city & state in one object
function city (city, state) {
  this.city = city;
  this.state = state;
}

function onFormSubmit (e) {
  // Set active sheet and store form information in variables
  //This function runs based off a formSubmit trigger
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sampleID'); 
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var lastRow = String(sheet.getLastRow());
  var email = String(sheet.getRange('D' +lastRow).getValue());
  var name = String(sheet.getRange('B' + lastRow).getValue());
  var company = String(sheet.getRange('C' + lastRow).getValue());
  var state = String(sheet.getRange('E' + lastRow).getValue()).split(",");
  var list_cities = [];

  //Separates City, State into object with City & State properties
  n = 0
  for (x of String(sheet.getRange('F' + lastRow).getValue()).split(",")) {
    if (n == 0) {
      var city_name = x.trim();
      n = 1;
    }
    else {
      n = 0;
      var temp = new city(city_name, x.trim());
      list_cities.push(temp);
    }
  }

  //Moves to next sheet
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheets()[1]);

  //Clear Form tab
  lastRow = String(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getLastRow());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRangeList(['A2:B2', 'A3:F' + lastRow]).clear();
  
  // Initializes first row
  var row = 2;
 
  //Fills in State column
  for (x of state) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).setValue(x.trim());
    row = row + 1;
  }
  
  //Fills in City column
  for (x of list_cities) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(x.state);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 2).setValue(x.city);
    row = row + 1
  }

  //List of cell column headers
  var letters = ["C", "D", "E", "F"];
  
  //Copies down formula for each column
  for (x of letters) {
    var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x + String(2));
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(x + String(2) + ":" + x + String(row-1));
    sourceRange.autoFill(destination, SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

  //Extracts only completed sheet
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/";
  var params = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();
  blob.setName(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getName() + ".xlsx");

  //Set email information and send email
  var message = {
    to: email,
    name: 'Name',
    subject: company + " Subject",
    body: "Body text",
    attachments: blob
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message)
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: I've added my code as well as an example form submission.

Comment: I've been experiencing the exact same issue. As of about 12 hours ago, my programmatic triggers, which all worked nominally the day before have been frequently failing to even execute,

Comment: I have a routine triggers and it failed from today morning. The same function works good when we ran manually.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like this is a problem in the v8 engine and is being looked into now:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184759540

To fix this issue in the meantime switching your code from runtime V8 to DEPRECATED_ES5 should fix the problem.

Bug aside, you're passing the event object through the onFormSubmit parameter but not using it.

Example:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  let response = e.namedValues;

  var email = response['Email:'];
  var name = response['Name:'];
  var company = response['Company:'];
  var state = response['State:'];

  //Remaining code below!
}
```

Getting the named values returns a object where the keys are the questions in the Google Form and the values are the answers in the form submission.